# Can't set up Ubuntu Desktop on VPS

Tags: apt, ssh, desktop-environments, vnc

I just had a Virtual Private Server setup with Ubuntu 19.10. I can login with SSH, but I can't successfully install Ubuntu Desktop. Here's what I did so far:

Create a new sudo user:

```
useradd NewUser
passwd NewUser
usermod -aG sudo NewUser
```

Install Ubuntu Desktop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

I then rebooted. I can login as root with SSH, but I can't get a VNC connection with TightVNC. It shows: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Did I miss something?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: Is VNC running? Are the ports working (no firewall etc. rules blocking connection)?

Comment: I have no idea. I followed the VPS vendor instructions. How can I check these?

Answer (score 0):

Is TightVNC Already installed? Make sure that TightVNC is installed and that the firewall has the correct ports open.